# Get java annotation attribute value on Spring SpEL expression

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations, spring-el

I need to implement an authorization expression on multiple controllers. For this I have decided to create a personalized annotation that facilitates its use. The problem is that the authorization expression requires a parameter (an id) that can be obtained in different ways in each controller. Then

I put the annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.hasAdminRole() || ( @authorizationService.hasParentRole() && @authorizationService.isYourSon(#son) )")
public @interface OnlyAccessForAdminOrParentOfTheSon {
    String son() default "";
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to get the value of the **"son"** attribute of the annotation to use in the SPEL authorization expression.

The notation I use as follows:

```
@OnlyAccessForAdminOrParentOfTheSon(son = "#id")
@OnlyAccessForAdminOrParentOfTheSon(son = "#socialMedia.son")
```

Someone knows how I can fix this.

Comment: Not possible with standard Spring-EL as the annotation and method invocation are not accesible via the context. You can write a custom org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased decission manager which adds your own ExtendedAccessDecisionVoter, which then parses custom @Security annotations Values. This has access to the method invokation and it's annotations. But maybe what you are trying to achive will better be handled by Access-Controll-Lists or a RoleHierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve like this, but spring Security methods allowing to define some custom authorization rules easily. These rules can grant or deny some of the operations for a particular user.

You need to create a custom service/component which will athenticate the request as per your requirement using @PreAuthorize annotationa with expression.

```
public interface CustomAuthorization {
boolean onlyAccessForAdminOrParentOfTheSon(final UserDetails principal, final long id) ;
}
```

Implementation :

```
@Component("customAuthorization")
public final class CustomAuthorizationImpl implementes CustomAuthorization {

    @Override
    public boolean onlyAccessForAdminOrParentOfTheSon(final UserDetails principal, final long id) {

        return // add you authentication condition;
    }

}
```

now you can use it with @PreAuthorize annotationa with expression

```
    @Service
    public final class HelloService {   

 @PreAuthorize("@customAuthorization.onlyAccessForAdminOrParentOfTheSon(principal, #id)")
            public String testMe(String id) {
                return "test successfully";
            }

        }
```

you can use it with and service/controller action, also you can modify the parameter as per your requirement.